# rgbdslam: How to get transform between poses?

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, pose, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to learn more about the general concept of rgbdslam. Let's say I found a rigid body transformation (represented by a 4x4 matrix) between two consecutive frames (more precisely, between the feature sets of these, if I understand correctly) by using RANSAC, how can I use this to calculate the transformation that represents the change in pose between these two frames?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35440/rgbdslam:-how-to-get-transform-between-poses?/) by [ph4nt0m](https://answers.ros.org/users/1315/ph4nt0m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2012-05-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is the inverse. The features are in the respective coordinate frames of the camera positions. So a transformation that moves the features from the first camera coordinate system to the second moves the second camera pose to the pose where it was in the first frame.

Edit: Correction.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ph4nt0m](https://answers.ros.org/users/1315/ph4nt0m/) on 2012-06-01**:
But if the camera moves towards some features (so that they come nearer, their z values decrease), then the feature-transform would be one that moves every point in opposite z direction. But the position of the camera itself (seen from a global coord. sys.) would have moved forward in this example.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-06-03**:
Yes, you are right, it is vice versa.